# The volume of $k$-parametrised manifolds when $k=1$ or $k=2$ or $k=3$ agrees respectively with the usual intuitive idea of length or area or volume.

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, solution-verification

James Munkres, at the chapter $22$-th of the text *Analysis on Manifolds*, gives the following definition.

[image]

Furthermore, to point out I say that the function $V\left(D\alpha\right)$ corresponds with volume of $k$-parallelopiped generated by the tangent vectors to the graphic of $\alpha$, that is it is the volume of $k$-parallelopided generated by the column vectors $\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x_k}$ of $D\alpha$. So, to justify the above definition, Munkres, as exercise, asks to show what follows.

[image]

If you like you can read the proof of the last theorem at the page $9$ of [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1744/8fd0ec7852840e98562f5f8d46088643ba50.pdf) document.

Well since own Munkres states that the theorem holds with more general hypotheses I thought to generalise it using the following considerations. So in the case where $\alpha$ is function from an open set of $\Bbb R^k$ in $\Bbb R^n$ then triangle $A$ is a general simplex and so the trasformation $h$ carries the simplex $A$ with origin the intersection of the axes and with edge the canonical versors onto a simplex $S$ with origin at $a$ and with edge the column vectors of $C$ so that considering that $v(A)=\frac 1{n!}$ and $v(S)=\frac 1{n!}|\det C|$ it seems to me the theorem could be generalised finding $n!$ disjoint and open simplexes whose union of the closures is the unit cube $[0,1]^n$.

So could someone help me, please?