# The alternating series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 - \sin k)}{2k}$ seems to be convergent, but Leibniz criterion does not apply

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

I was looking for an example of convergent, alternating series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kb_k$ such that $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is not eventually monotone, so that Leibiniz criterion could not be applied. Preferably, one whose convergence is conditional (not absolute). So, I thought of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 - \sin k)}{2k}$. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28-1%29%5En%282%20-%20sin%28n%29%29%2F%282n%29) says that this series converges, and it is clearly not absolutely convergent. But I am trying to prove its convergence, and I haven't been successful so far. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The exact value of the series is $\frac{1}{4}-\ln 2$. Splitting the sum as $\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ and $\frac{(-1)^k \sin k}{2k}$ may help. Or realizing that $2-\sin k \le 3$ and then using the alternating series test. I don't know if either of these methods is mathematically sound though.

Comment: @Varun Splitting the sum is justified by showing one of the two resulting series is finite, which is elementary for the first one, so that's fine.  Bounding $2-\sin(x) \leq 3$ doesn't help, though.

Comment: If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(2 - \sin k)}{2k} = \frac{1}{4} - \ln 2$, and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k} = -\ln 2$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\sin k}{2k} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: The problem now is: how to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\sin k}{2k}$ converges? Equivalently, how to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\sin k}{k}$ converges? This is another alternating series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^kb_k$ such that $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is not eventually monotone, so Leibniz criterion does no apply.

Comment: Do you know Abel's test for complex power series?

Comment: I realized just now that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin k}{k}$ converges. Maybe the integral test can be used to justify it. So, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\sin k}{k}$ converges absolutely.

Comment: If I have already studied Abel test, then I forgot it.

Comment: Note that $\sum \frac{\sin k}{k}$ doesn't converge absolutely (i assume you mistakenly thought $\sin k \geq 0$).  Abel's test tells us that $\sum \frac{1}{k} z^k$ converges for all $|z|\leq 1, z\neq 1$, and setting $z=-e^i$ gives us the series we want.

Comment: You're right, I thought, for a moment, that $\frac{\sin k}{k}$ was positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k \sin k}{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\cos (\pi k) \sin k}{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin ((\pi +1)k)}{2k}$$

and the right hand side series converges by Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Of course the other part $\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ converges by AST.

Comment: $\cos (\pi k) \sin k = \sin(\pi k + k)$?

Comment: $\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$ and $\sin \pi k = 0$

Comment: Sorry, I'm sleepy, underperforming.

Comment: @RRL Hi, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810762/the-volume-of-k-parametrised-manifolds-when-k-1-or-k-2-or-k-3-agrees-res), please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Comment: @RRL Thanks!!! Furthermore (I hope this will encourage you to answer) I think that tomorrow I will put a bounty for the question. Thanks too much again for your attention!!!