# Existence of holomorphic 3rd root for $f = 4z+z^2+e^z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Considering the function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, z \to 4z + z^2+ e^z$ as well as $\mathbb{E} := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$ I have to proof that there does not exist a holomorphic function $w: \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $(w(z))^3 = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{E}$.

I have already proven that $f$ has exactly one (simple) zero in $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$. I also know that $f$ has no holomorphic $l: \mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{l(z)} = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{E}$.

I tried proving the statement by contradiction as well as using what I already know but I did not see how that proof might work. Has anyone another idea or could show how it works using contradiction (if it works that way)?

Comment: If you have a simple zero, then there cannot be a holomorphic cube root in a neighbourhood of it: what would be the multiplicity of the zero of cube root at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$w(z_0)=0$ if $f(z_0)=0$. This implies that $W(z)=(z-z_0) g(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g$ in  a neighborhood of $z_0$ and this in turn shows that $f$ must have a zero of order at least $3$ at $z_0$.

Comment: Hi, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810762/the-volume-of-k-parametrised-manifolds-when-k-1-or-k-2-or-k-3-agrees-res), please?